# "data" field in JSON response using SuperGraph as library

Tags: json, http, go, encoding

Using [SuperGraph](https://github.com/dosco/super-graph) as library I found JSON responses does not start with: `"data"`.

Example:

```
{
  "players": [...]
}
```

instead of:

```
{
  "data": {
    "players": [...]
  }
}
```

I'm using this code:

```golang
func main() {
    sg, err := core.NewSuperGraph(nil, sb)

    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Post(config.ApiEndpoint, myHandler(sg))
    })

    StartServer(r)
}

type reqBody struct {
    Query string `json:"query"`
}

func sgHandler(sg *core.SuperGraph, next http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var rBody reqBody
        bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        _ = r.Body.Close(
        r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes))
        err := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(bodyBytes)).Decode(&rBody)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Error parsing JSON request body", 400)
        }

        res, err := sg.GraphQL(ctx, rBody.Query, nil)
        if err == nil {
            result, _ := json.Marshal(res.Data) // IS THIS WRONG?
            _, err = w.Write(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Is it my fault?

Is this wrong? `result, _ := json.Marshal(res.Data)`?

Maybe I need to Marshal all `res`? Isn't it heavier?